# google maps v3 close info window (outside function) and marker click function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

Explanation of title

I have a google maps with several markers each has a info window.

Actions:

User clicks in marker and listener is triggered - OK
User clicks in a onclick function [myclick(i)] the info window (specific marker) is displayed

Errors:

myclick(i) works the first time, after that will not!

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var markers = [];

var locations = [    
['PLace 1', -8.2306155581, 37.0871796116, 'A', 'info 1'],
['Place 2', -8.5448366404, 37.1314707841, 'B', 'info 2']];



function showmap() {
  $('#results_map').toggle();

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.083, -8.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  var i;

  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][1]),
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+locations[i][3]+'|FF0000|FFFFFF',
      title: locations[i][0]
    });

    markers[i].info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: locations[i][4]
    }); 


    markers[i].setMap(map);

  }

google.maps.event.addListener(markers[0], 'click', function(){
        $(document.body).scrollTo('#placeA', 800, 'swing');
        markers[0].info.close();
      });       
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[1], 'click', function(){
    $(document.body).scrollTo('#placeB', 800, 'swing');
    markers[1].info.close();
  });       

}

function myclick(i) { 
  $(document.body).scrollTo('#results', 800, 'swing');

  markers[i].info.open(map, markers[i]);  

}

</script>

<div id="results_map"><div id="map"></div></div>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myclick(0)">Map 1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myclick(1)">Map 2</a>
```

Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your help

hort

Comment: What javascript errors are you getting? I don't see an include of jQuery, but that might just be an oversight on your part.

Comment: @geocodezip: Jquery is included via googleapis
`code`
Error: TypeError: d.N is not a function
Source File: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/14/main.js
Line: 80 `code`

Comment: I don't see anything that would include it (unless it is in js/jquery.scrollTo.js, which is not "googleapis code").  That error is not helpful, please post a link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip (http://jsfiddle.net/uCUDJ/1/) I believe that now is everything there, thank you